# Unknown Taylor expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have come across a few apparently related Taylor expansions, as detailed below:

\begin{align}
&\dots\frac{a^7}{140}-\frac{a^6}{80}-\frac{3 a^5}{40}-\frac{a^4}{8}+\frac{a^2}{2}+a+1&&=\exp \left(a-\frac{a^3}{6}\right)&\tag{1}\\
\\
&\dots\frac{11 a^7 b}{1120}+\frac{a^6 b}{32}+\frac{a^5 b}{40}-\frac{a^4 b}{16}-\frac{a^3 b}{4}-\frac{a^2 b}{4}+\frac{b}{2}&&=?&\tag{2}\\
\end{align}

The first was fairly easy to guess the closed form on the RHS, but the bottom one I am stuck on. The extra $b$ is obviously doing something to the coefficients, but I don't know what. Are there any good strategies for finding a closed form for $(2$)?

Unfortunately, I don't have any background information on them, so much is pure guesswork.

## Update

All known coefficients  for $(2)$:

$$\frac{1}{2},0,-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{40},\frac{1}{32},\frac{11}{1120},-\frac{1}{1280},-\frac{43}{20160}$$

Comment: The extra $b$ just multiplies the series and the function by $b.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac{1}{2} (1-a)\exp\left(a-\frac{a^3}{6}\right)=
\frac{1}{2}-\frac{a^2}{4}-\frac{a^3}{4}-\frac{a^4}{16}+\frac{a^5}{40}+\frac{a^6}{32}+\frac{11 a^7}{1120}-\frac{a^8}{1280}-\frac{43
   a^9}{20160}-\frac{69 a^{10}}{89600}+O\left(a^{11}\right)
$$

Comment: Quick answer! Did you find it by inspection only? +1

Comment: Actually I used computer. Seeing that the first answer was exponent, I multiplied the second polynomial by $2/b$, applied logarithm and expanded into series: 
$$
-\frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{a^3}{2}-\frac{a^4}{4}-\frac{a^5}{5}-\frac{a^6}{6}-\frac{a^7}{7}-\frac{a^8}{8}-\frac{a^9}{9}+O\left(a^{10}\right),\quad a\to0.
$$
Starting from the forth term it is the expansion of $\log(1-a)$. Subtraction of it gives the rest.

Comment: Clever approach! :-)

Comment: @Andrew fantastic! thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Andrew could you please explain in more detail what you mean by "applied logarithm and expanded into series" - I think then the answer would be more helpul for future readers :)

Comment: @martin it is as follows:
$$\log\left[2\left( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{a^2}{4}-\frac{a^3}{4}-\frac{a^4}{16}+\frac{a^5}{40}+\frac{a^6}‌​{32}+\frac{11 a^7}{1120}-\frac{a^8}{1280}-\frac{43    a^9}{20160}\right)\right]=$$
$$
-\frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{a^3}{2}-\frac{a^4}{4}-\frac{a^5}{5}-\frac{a^6}{6}-\frac{a‌​^7‌​}{7}-\frac{a^8}{8}-\frac{a^9}{9}+O\left(a^{10}\right),\quad a\to0,
$$the rhs is the Maclaurin series of the lhs.